# Does Orb of Disruption prevent using abilities on self?

Tags: werewolv.es

If you're holding an Orb of Disruption, can you carry out an ability that targets yourself? Like a self-Protect, SS shift, a Messiah sacrifice, etc....?

I would assume not, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Orb of disruption blocks the holder as well as anyone that visits them:

> Disruption Orb :
>
> Role-blocks anyone who visits the holder that isn't
> night immune. However, it will role-block you every night as well.

-From the How to Play

So unless they are immune to roleblocks, the holder can not perform any actions, including ones that self-visit.

Comment: If only I had reread the item description x) Only had half the item description in my mind apparently...